# How to make a border teleporter from doodle jump

Tags: unity, c#

Right now I'm using this code, but the transition glitches from one border to another

```
void Start()
{
    if(isLeft == false)
    {
        destination = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("LeftBorder").GetComponent<Transform>();
    }
    else
    {
        destination = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("RightBorder").GetComponent<Transform>();
    }
}

private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, collision.transform.position) > distance)
    {
        collision.transform.position = new Vector2(destination.position.x, destination.position.y);
    }
   
}
```

Comment: Assume your reader has not played doodle jump. Explain the behaviour that you want this code to achieve, and how precisely the current behaviour differs from that.

Comment: A player character is moving to the right, as soon as he dissapeares from the screen, player character reapers from the left side of the screen

Comment: Start is only executed once. This code should not work when you decide to go the other way.

Comment: @koogel Please edit your question to include your clarifying explanation directly in your question post. Comments are somewhat temporary - if the information is important, it should be edited into the corresponding question/answer.